# Running desktop entry causes program to start then close without ever showing

Tags: sudo, .desktop, xampp

I'm trying to make a desktop entry for Xampp on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's what I have so far..

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Comment=Launch XAMPP Manager
Keywords=XAMPP,php,apache
Name=Xampp
Terminal=false
Exec=sudo -i /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Hidden=false
Icon=xampp
Name[en_US]=xampp
```

However, when I run this the icon just pops up and then fades away like this..

[image]

without ever actually opening.

Comment: Hi Ryan, do you have gksudo installed? What happens if you run the same command from the terminal? The issue is that `sudo -i` does not know how to ask you for your password, unless run from a terminal. `pkexec` is not working on gui applications just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `sudo -i` with `gksudo` or (better yet) `pkexec` -- this will create a graphical prompt for the root password, rather than asking for it in an inaccesible console

Comment: Interesting, when I try gksudo I get "There was an error launching the application".

When I try pkexec I get the prompt for my password, but then the same thing happens..  it pops up on the launcher, flashes for a bit then closes.  Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you type `sudo -i /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run` in a terminal? Any error messages?